# Better stdbool.h

Tags: c, libraries, boolean

How about instead of

```
#define bool _Bool
#define true 1
#define false 0
#define __bool_true_false_are_defined 1
```

We should have this:

```
#define bool _Bool
#define true (bool)1
#define false (bool)0
#define __bool_true_false_are_defined (bool)1
```

so that the issue specified in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47010910/why-does-sizeofa-true-false-give-an-output-of-four-bytes) won't happen, by casting the literals into one-byte bools instead of leaving them four-byte integers? Where can I officially propose this?

Another change is, how about we get rid of `_Bool` altogether and just have `bool` built in?

Comment: How is the issue described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47010910/why-does-sizeofa-true-false-give-an-output-of-four-bytes) a problem? The sizes of the expressions `false` and `true` rarely matter. The size of a `bool` or `_Bool` object is 1 byte.

Answer (score 4):

Your suggestions for `true` and `false` make them unsuitable for use in `#if` preprocessing macros, something that the language standard specifically mentions.

One reason to not have `bool` built in is the volume of existing code that defines a `bool` type or macro.  Having `bool` be a built-in type would break this existing code.

Comment: It wouldn't break existing code

Comment: @0x10 If you're suggesting making `bool` a keyword, of course it would break existing code. Any program (likely pre-C99 but still valid in C99 and C11) that has something like `typedef enum { false, true } bool;` would fail to compile if `bool` became a keyword. If you suggest making `bool` a typedef defined in `<stdbool.h>`, that wouldn't break existing code that doesn't include that header (directly or indirectly!) -- but how would `bool` be defined?

Comment: It would also make `__bool_true_false_are_defined` unsuitable for use in `#if` -- and that's the whole point of it.

Comment: @KeithThompson If we made `bool` a keyword, then `<stdbool.h>` could change to reflect that.

Comment: @0x10 Yes, of course. But if we made `bool` a keyword, it would break existing C code that uses `bool` as an identifier.

Comment: To carry OP's basic idea about `#define true (bool)1`, C could have offered a `bool` suffix , say `t`,   and then did `#define true 1t`.  IIRC pre-processor math does not have trouble with `1`, `1L`, `1LL` - treats them all as `(intmax_t)1`.  Yet too much history to change the type of `true` now.